# How can I make the whole string in quotes if there are already quotes in the String?

Tags: string, quotes

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.twitch.tv/minideer");

driver.findElement(By.xpath(//*[@id="ember854"]/a)).click();
```

I would like to make the xPath all in quotes. How would I do this?

Comment: Please label the question with the language you are using.

Comment: Also you can select code snippets and use the "code" button to make it appear as code in the rendering, that'd be easier to read.